# Using bootstrap vue pagination how to make an axios call for each page?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Reference https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/pagination

```js
data() {
    return {
      currentPage: 1,
    }

    computed: {
        rows() {
          return this.productsList.length;
        },

        methods() {
          layoutchange() {

              this.layout = !this.layout;

              if (this.layout === true) {

                this.listProducts();
              } else {

                this.gridProducts();
              }
            },
            gridProducts() {
              let project_key = 'https://.....url'
              const categoryUrl = project_key + '/................offset=0&limit=12';
              const sendGetRequest = async() => {
                let access_token = await axios.request({
                  method: "get",
                  baseURL: categoryUrl,
                  headers: {
                    'Authorization': "Bearer " + accToken,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                  },
                  data: {}
                }).then((response) => {
                  if (response) {
                    // this.productsList = response.body;
                    this.productsList = response.data.results;
                    // eslint-disable-next-line
                    console.log(this.productsList);
                  }
                });
              };
              sendGetRequest();
            }



          listProducts() {
            let project_key = 'https://.....url'
            const categoryUrl = project_key + '/................offset=0&limit=8';
            const sendGetRequest = async() => {
              let access_token = await axios.request({
                method: "get",
                baseURL: categoryUrl,
                headers: {
                  'Authorization': "Bearer " + accToken,
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                data: {}
              }).then((response) => {
                if (response) {
                  // this.productsList = response.body;
                  this.productsList = response.data.results;
                  // eslint-disable-next-line
                  console.log(this.productsList);
                }
              });
            };
            sendGetRequest();
          }
```

```html
<ul v-if="layout == true">

  <div class="listview-plp" v-for="product in productsList" :key="product.key" id="product" :items="productsList" :current-page="currentPage">
    <div class="da">sdds</div>
    <b-pagination v-model="currentPage" :total-rows="rows" @change="handlePageChange"></b-pagination>
</ul>



<ul v-if="layout == false">

  <div class="listview-plp" v-for="product in productsList" :key="product.key" id="product" :items="productsList" :current-page="currentPage">
    <div class="da">sdds</div>
    <b-pagination v-model="currentPage" :total-rows="rows" @change="handlePageChange"></b-pagination>
</ul>
```

I am working on pagination for grid and list view in vuejs, the problem here is i want to display pagination for both like if it is grid view-(12 items per page) and if it is list view(8 items per page), All this i am getting from an api with offset and limit values, So i need to call an API for each page. to get it work. So i am not sure how to call api for each page using  and to handle in for loop so (in my case layoutchange() method)

in grid view page1 (offset0, limit 12) page2-(offset12, limit 24) page3 (offset24 limit 36)....
in list view page1 (offset0, limit 8) page2-(offset8, limit 16) page3 (offset16 limit 24)....

Below i have taken two methods and called an api inside it like gridProducts and listProducts.(where the api is working fine with 12 and 8 items) initially.

So please help me with, Calling an api per each page using b-pagination, simultaneously using for loop for grid and list view

Comment: First your snippet has a syntax error, please fix it. Then, why would you want to copy the code of your api call twice according to view ? You should divide the logic : the api call is one thing, the way you display the data (grid or list) is another one. Finally, to answer your question on layout change : you could store a `currentLayout` data property and use a watcher to react to its changing value :https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

Comment: @Pierre_T, Sorry to say that i provided sample code here, so snippet will not work.

Comment: @Pierre_T the way of displaying data is working fine, But  not sure, Using <b-pagination> how to call api on 2nd page.

Comment: @Pierre_T At present in data i am using currentPage: 1, According to that api call is success, But for 2nd page not sure how to call api, ??? Sorry if my question is not understandable

Comment: I am not sure Im getting what you want : I understand `listProducts()` and `gridProducts()` are getting data from the same api. If so, I would avoid duplicating twice the get method (what you did with `listProducts()` and `gridProducts()`) and rather make a generic one `fetchProducts` with a limit of `24` if you need, and then let the pagination logic be handled elsewhere

Comment: @Pierre_T Generally i have taken listProducts() and gridProducts() because i want products to display using two variations. In the Api  call i am getting  Offset and limit. to display data like if grid 12 items and list 8 items.